# Serialize data into json using Python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have 70 GB of files, mostly TXT, CSV and logs sourcing from publicly disclosed information either for research, training neural networks etc. I would like to serialize to json every line in that files and push to elastic search to make use of it. Lines might contain special characters that json encoder should escape like Russian letters, Korean etc. I cannot just take a 10 GB file, encode it as a one object and push it to elastic because of Apache Lucene file size limitation.

Most of the entries contains:

```
9:username:someemail@gstuff:eafff17afbef485a894][;'.f6d39c56b79:
254:Starcius:someemail@gstuff:09160da290bcd1f83fssf0bd260e13d4f:
2:username:someemail@gstuff:104b77708bb7c19b9f913449c923a898:8
2:username:someemail@gstuff:efc38fca88d8e58089adccce3e05f93
254:username:someemail@gstuff:880896502dd68b546258\][;.'54cca34
2:username:someemail@gstuff:647b61ba8f0965e762c579e5b3da9eca:hUr
2:username:someemail@gstuff::3e9478fcecb4e90266art87g8fiuba90c6ed5473c:\^c
2:username:someemail@gstuff:9df5783228asdasddas796e18cb12e44da:,M|
```

I want to take each line of the file (delimited by new line) and produce something like (escaping the illegal json characters):

```
{"data":"9:username:someemail@gstuff:eafff17afbef485a894][;\'.f6d39c56b79:"},
{"data":"9:username:someemail@gstuff:eafff17afbef485a894][;\'.f6d39c56b79:"},
{"data":"9:username:someemail@gstuff:eafff17afbef485a894][;\'.f6d39c56b79:"}
```

What would it be the best approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below does not read all in memory. Since you talk 10Gb files this
might be of importance. I would do it like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json


def convert2json(filename):
    with open(filename) as I:
        for line in I:
            d = {"data": line}
            print(json.dumps(d))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    convert2json(sys.argv[1])

% python scriptname.py yourfile
{"data": "9:username:someemail@gstuff:eafff17afbef485a894][;'.f6d39c56b79:\n"}
{"data": "254:Starcius:someemail@gstuff:09160da290bcd1f83fssf0bd260e13d4f:\n"}
{"data": "2:username:someemail@gstuff:104b77708bb7c19b9f913449c923a898:8\n"}
{"data": "2:username:someemail@gstuff:efc38fca88d8e58089adccce3e05f93\n"}
{"data": "254:username:someemail@gstuff:880896502dd68b546258\\][;.'54cca34\n"}
{"data": "2:username:someemail@gstuff:647b61ba8f0965e762c579e5b3da9eca:hUr\n"}
{"data": "2:username:someemail@gstuff::3e9478fcecb4e90266art87g8fiuba90c6ed5473c:\\^c\n"}
{"data": "2:username:someemail@gstuff:9df5783228asdasddas796e18cb12e44da:,M|\n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

read_my_file = open("my_file.txt","r") #open your file, I copied and paste your example in my file

lines= read_my_file.readlines()#read each line separatelly
my_list=[]#create my new list of items

for i in lines:#do a for loop for all the element in lines
    my_list.append({"data":i})#for each loop create a dictionary and append it on my list

print (my_list)#print my list to ensure that it's correct

my_json=json.dumps(my_list)#convert my list to json
print (my_json)#print my json
```

Please let me know if you need some extra details ;)